# Airflow issues: ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, airflow

I am using Airflow and trying to access Tableau API following the guidelines mentioned in this [post](https://medium.com/snake-charmer-python-and-analytics/tableau-server-on-tap-authenticating-with-a-personal-access-token-7f4affaece3e).

However, I am getting the following error message when on `localhost:8080`. I tried multiple things mentioned in different posts at Stack Overflow like setting the
`requests.get('https://site_name.com', verify=False)`
or specifying the path of the certificates in the verify `"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\ssl\\certs"`
Then I get a different error message saying the path is invalid.

I am new to SSL and dont know how all this works. So, I am shooting blindly without understanding what the actual problem is. I would appreciate if you can advise me some resources to learn from, along with pointing me to how i can solve this problem.

**Error Message**

```
Broken DAG: \[/opt/airflow/dags/ExceltoDB.py\] Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1077, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 446, in increment
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='analytics', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='analytics', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [urllib and "SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error)

Comment: Yes, try to use the lib "urllib3". And additional "urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)" if you want to. But be careful!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `extra_options={"verify":False}` to your `SimpleHttpOperator`